# Differentiate GET and POST in a ModelViewset Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, web-services, rest

I would like to know what I have to do to differentiate GET and POST in a ModelViewSet in Django Rest Framework becouse it mix bought and I have no idea how to do it.

---

Basically I want to make an api that allows to upload two images and the response of a POST call is a number depending on the degree of similarity of the uploaded images. For this I intend by means of the POST call to get the path where the images are stored to be able to work with them in OpenCV in another script. Then I put the code I have, which allows you to upload the two images.

```
## Models.py ##
    class Task(models.Model):
        task_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/',default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')
        image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/', default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')

        def __str__(self):
            return  "%s" % self.task_name
    ## Serializers.py ##

    class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    image1 = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None,use_url=True)
    image2 = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model =  Task
        fields = ('id','task_name','image1','image2')

## Views.py ##

    class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Task.objects.all()
        serializer_class = TaskSerializer

## Urls.py ##

    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register(r'task', views.TaskViewSet) urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^',include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you mean differentiate get and post? that is the whole point of a view set

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you need to compare your images after you created a Task.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route
from rest_framework.response import Response

class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
        def perform_task(self, request, pk=None):
            task = self.get_object()
            serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            task.save()
            # here you run your code to set similarity
            return Response({'similarity': similarity})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```